# innerHTML not displaying in the DOM, no errors in the console

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

This might be something trivial to solve, but I can't seem to figure it out. document.getElementById selects the tspan I'm trying to write data to, but nothing shows up. Code as follows. The var percentAS is set to 71, which is working fine. No errors in the console. Note this is a minimized version of my code there's actually a lot more in the document.

```
<body>
    <text id="data" fill="white" x="460" y="160">
        {{signups.[0]}} -
        <tspan id="percentAS"></tspan>
    </text>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("percentAS").innerHTML = percentAS + "%";
</script>
```

I tried logging some data to the console to see what was going on:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("percentAS"));
```

And this is returned in the error console:

```
tspan#percentAS.[object SVGAnimatedString]
  innerHTML: "71%"
  __proto__: SVGTSpanElementPrototype
```

**EDIT** Others have asked for more context, but I know for sure that there is nothing interfering with what I pasted above, or I would have added more context. It's just some basic sgv polygons that are a huge pain to read because they have so many points, which is why I didn't include them.

**EDIT 2** It appears that my issue is unique to the Safari web browser, as I opened it in Chrome and Firefox and it works perfectly fine. I can't find any known issues with Safari in regards to this, although I've found a couple blog posts from a few years ago detailing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem with Safari web browser itself and not the code. I switched to using jQuery to do it:

```
 $("#percentAS").append(percentAS + "%");
```

and it worked just fine in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that in your Javascript, the variable `percentAs` is not bound to anything.

If you gave it a value, such as `var percentAs = 45` it would work.

EDIT: As per someone's comment. It would be nice to see where `percentAs` is being declared in your code since that could effect the way functions work that try to access it.

Comment: If `percentAs` were never declared, there would be an error. Logging also shows that it has value `71%`, though OP hasn't posted the code where the value is assigned.

Comment: The asker said that the variable `percentAs` is set to 71.

Comment: As i said in my updated quesiton: perhaps his `percentAs` is being declared after is he trying to use it.

Answer (score -1):

This is working fine. There must be something else going wrong in your code.

```js
var percentAS = 71;
document.getElementById("percentAS").innerHTML = percentAS + "%";
```

```html
<text id="data" fill="white" x="460" y="160">{{signups.[0]}} -
    <tspan id="percentAS"></tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Did you noticed the [svg] tag?

Comment: @Teemu I thought it was weird the question had that tag... What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Well, it's not clearly appearing in the code (maybe too much minimized), but `text` and `tspan` are `svg` elements.

Comment: @Teemu OK, can you give an example of why that is relevant when setting the innerHTML of a tspan element? I've shown that what the asker is trying to accomplish actually works, if done as shown, so there must be something else going on causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is something else going on, namely `SVG`. You can see it in the console logging OP has provided. Btw. Not my downvotes on this post.